# No data showing when adding delimited text layer with lat/long

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, csv

See screenshot of Data Source Manager of Delimited Text input. Sample data look fine.

[image: Screen shot of Data Source Manager before pressing add]

When I press 'Add' no data shows. World Map layer is EPSG-3857-WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. Am I using the wrong CRS? Using MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave and QGIS 3.12.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates you are trying to add, are not EPSG:3857 coordinates. They seem to be EPSG:4326 coordinates. Maybe your data is added, but at the wrong place. Try zooming on lat/lon 0,0 (at the coast of Africa) to check it. If they are there, setting Geometry CRS to EPSG:4326 should solve the problem.

EDIT:
Your coordinates are treated as text fields because of the ° characters. Delete them and it will work fine.

Comment: No sign of plot at 0,0, but I changed the Geometry CRS to EPSG:4326, with no improvement. So then added a file named locations.csvt containing “Real”,”Real","String" with no change either.

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: Sorry slow - been off-line - see https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcjldf2gdg346m1/locations.csv?dl=0

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try using WGS84 EPSG:4326